# Why shell is crashing using "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" after standard installation approach with ubuntu 16.04 xenial?

Tags: ros, bashrc, shell, ubuntu, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,
recently i tried to install ros with the standard installation method from http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu
with the follwing steps:

1)

```
sudo sh -c '. /etc/lsb-release && echo "deb http://packages.ros.org.ros.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/ros/ubuntu $DISTRIB_CODENAME main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

2)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
```

3)

```
sudo apt-get update
```

4)

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

5)

```
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update
```

Warning: running 'rosdep update' as root is not recommended.
You should run 'sudo rosdep fix-permissions' and invoke 'rosdep update' again without sudo.

```
sudo rosdep fix-permissions
```

6)

```
echo "source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

....and  this is what i'm encountering in my console:

```
File "<string>", line 1
    import os; print(os.pathsep.join([x for x in "/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/inecho/bin:/home/inecho/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/sk/android-sdk-linux/tools:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/sk/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools".split(os.pathsep) if not any([d for d in ['cturtle', 'diamondback', 'electric', 'fuerte'] if d in x])]))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
bash: cat: No such file or directory
bash: cat: No such file or directory
bash: python: No such file or directory
bash: awk: No such file or directory
bash: grep: No such file or directory
```

Afterwards i am not able to type any of shell-commands like `ls` until i uncomment the line in `~/.bashrc` again. This is what happens:

```
inecho@inecho-P50:~$ ls
bash: ls: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone has a clue whats happening there?

The last lines of my `.bashrc`now with the uncommented `setup.bash`:

```
# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export PATH=${PATH}:/home/sk/android-sdk-linux/tools:/usr/local/cuda/bin
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/sk/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64
# source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251643/why-shell-is-crashing-using-%22source-/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash%22-after-standard-installation-approach-with-ubuntu-16.04-xenial?/) by [rosrud](https://answers.ros.org/users/29002/rosrud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-01-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-10**:
Is your shell actually `bash`?

Also: it would probably help if you posted some lines from your `.bashrc` file, preferably the ones surrounding the `source /opt/ros/..` line.

**Comment by [rosrud](https://answers.ros.org/users/29002/rosrud/) on 2017-01-10**:
yes, my shell is bash. i double checked it with `echo $SHELL`.
i updated my post with the last lines of my `.bashrc` if it helps

**Comment by [Michael Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/26650/michael-johnson/) on 2017-01-10**:
Where is your `JAVA_HOME` being set? What does your `/etc/environment` file look like? What about `echo $PATH`

**Comment by [rosrud](https://answers.ros.org/users/29002/rosrud/) on 2017-01-10**:
my `/etc/enviroment` says `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java"`. How can i interpret this? Btw. i'm using linux for a half a year actively so i'm quite unexperienced :)

**Comment by [Michael Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/26650/michael-johnson/) on 2017-01-10**:
If that is all one line, try splitting it in two and then `source /etc/environment`. I think that should fix it.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java"
```

**Comment by [rosrud](https://answers.ros.org/users/29002/rosrud/) on 2017-01-10**:
i changed it without any improvement. still the same error..

**Comment by [Michael Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/26650/michael-johnson/) on 2017-01-10**:
Hmm, what does `echo $PATH` output?

**Comment by [rosrud](https://answers.ros.org/users/29002/rosrud/) on 2017-01-10**:
the same as above for PATH and additionally`JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/sk/android-sdk-linux/tools:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/home/sk/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools`

**Comment by [Michael Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/26650/michael-johnson/) on 2017-01-10**:
I'm not sure I understand. For example I get this when I type the command:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I managed to reproduce this problem by modifying my `/etc/environment` file to match your one line and then restarting:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java"
```

to

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" 
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java"
```

To fix this I was able to split the line in two and then restart (relog should work as well).

This seems to be a bug in either python os library or the ROS scripts usage of it as sourcing that file should work even if they are on a single line.

p.s. if your terminal can't find the commands again you can copy/paste `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"` to get them back.

---

Originally posted by [Michael Johnson](https://answers.ros.org/users/26650/michael-johnson/) with karma: 154 on 2017-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosrud](https://answers.ros.org/users/29002/rosrud/) on 2017-01-11**:
Thanks a lot! It worked.
It was important to perform a **reboot**, after i seperated the line in two rows and everything went well. So was it the python split-function which couldn't handle this?